# Lua pattern doesn't work

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I have trouble on my test script

```
names.txt contents
foo 1
test 0

data="names.txt"
name="test"
--
d=io.open(data,"r")
s=d:read("*a")
f=string.gsub(s,"%"..name,"%1 1")
print(f)
print"------"
print(f:gsub("(%w+)%s*(%d)","%1"):format("%s"))
```

output on lua

```
foo 1
test 1 0
------
foo
test 0
```

I would like to get the first number with string

```
from test 0 to test 1
```

I hope someone can help me

Comment: ...what? Could you explain a bit better what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a file with names and numbers inside, the names will be different for each user, if a user is online, the number will 1 else 0.
but I would like that the rest remains unchanged in the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you are trying to do?

```
data="names.txt"
name="test"
--
d=io.open(data,"r")
s=d:read("*a")
f=string.gsub(s,"(" .. name .. ")%s+%d+","%1 1")
print(f)
```

Result:

```
foo 1
test 1
```

If not, please be more precise. What output do you want?

Comment: thanks that Is was I trying to do.
thank you very much

Comment: keep in mind that this pattern breaks if `name` contains any pattern control chars like `%`, `.`, `-`, `(`, etc. You should prepare the name first by properly escaping those control chars -- or use a more generic pattern (like `(%w+)%s+%d+`) followed by simple string comparison (`if capture == name then...`).